# How to re-use power point slides, but not by copying them?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a power point presentation that has a slide containing contact details. I want to include this slide in my other presentations, but not by having it copied as the power point  re-use function does.

What I want to achieve is that when I make changes to the original power point slide (contact details), I want it to be changed in all presentations using that slide without having to go and change them by hand.

Maybe some kind of hyperlink solution?

Using Microsoft PowerPoint 2010.

Comment: You could put it in an Excel table and then embed that...I'm pretty sure Excel tables will update on change.

Comment: This also does not work, it makes a copy of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open the presentation containing your contact details slide and put PPT in slide sorter view.
Select the contact details slide.

Switch to another presentation that needs this slide, insert a new slide (preferably blank) then use the Paste Special command and choose to Link.

If necessary, enlarge the linked slide image to fill your new slide.

Comment: It does not work, when I make changes to the contact details slide, it doesn't change in the new presentation I linked it from. (Still looks like it's adding a copy of the slide)

Comment: If you're getting a completely new slide, you're not in the correct view when copying the original or paste/linking it into the other presentations.  Can you select the pasted slide and reduce it so that it doesn't fill the slide you've pasted it into?  If not, there's something wrong in the way you're doing the copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the effect you want like this:

1. Create a new presentation and on the first slide put your contact details.
2. Save the presentation
3. Open the presentation you need the contact details in.
4. Go to the insert tab.
5. Select object
6. Select the Create from file radio button
7. browse to the powerpoint file you saved in step 2
8. check the Link box
9. Click OK

To verify it worked, modify the presentation saved in step 2. Close your open presentation displaying the contact information. When you reopen the presentation you will be presented with a dialog notifying you the original file has changed and asking if you want to update the link. Click Update Links.

For more information read this [article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/link-or-embed-a-powerpoint-slide-HA010120811.aspx).